# AndEngine GLES vs AndEngine GLES2

Tags: android, android-intent, andengine

I found this code on AndEngine GLES `engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true);`

the problem is how to make that code on AndEngine GLES2?

Comment: You can manually call RunOnUpdateThread as needed, which what I have been doing in my projects.

Comment: please exlain more spesific...
i don't get it....

sorry, i'm newbie

Answer (score 2):

That line, in GLES1, tells to the engine that touch events will run on update thread instead of the main (UI) thread. It's like if all the code inside touch events were executed through "runOnUpdateThread" method.

In GLES2, touch events run on update thread by default. So you don't need that line of code.